# Cartesian product

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a question. How do I prove that the cardinality of the Cartesian  product of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ (reals) equals to the cardinality of the continuum?

Comment: What do you mean with _"R with R (rationals)"_? Do you mean reals, or are you using 'R' for the rationals? The cartesian product of countable sets is countable, so $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable. Perhaps you mean 'reals' instead of 'rationals', so $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @StackTD Yes! Sorry ! I will edit it.

Comment: Do you know cardinal arithmetic or are you looking for an explicit function to show an injection/bijection?

Comment: @StackTD If it's not a bother, I'd like to see both of the ways (cardinal artithemtic and an explicit function) Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|\mathbb{R}| = 2^{\aleph_0}$, you easily have:
$$|\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}|\cdot|\mathbb{R}|=\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^2 = 2^{2 \cdot \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$$

In fact, for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$, you have $\kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa$ and for infinite cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ more generally that $\kappa \cdot \lambda = \mbox{max}\left\{ \kappa , \lambda\right\}$.

---

Without cardinal arithmetic, you can show $|\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}|$ by giving injective functions:

- $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ showing that $|\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}| \ge |\mathbb{R}|$
- $f :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ showing that $|\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}| \le |\mathbb{R}|$

The first one is trivial. I can add a sketch for the second injection if you want.

---

Since $\mathbb{R}$ can be bijectively mapped to $(0,1)$, you can bijectively map $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $(0,1) \times (0,1)$, an "open square". Now pick an element $(x,y) \in (0,1) \times (0,1)$ and write down the unique decimal expansions (excluding infinite repeating 9's) of $x$ and $y$.

Construct a new number $z \in (0,1)$ by picking the decimals of $x$ and $y$ in an alternating way, then different pairs $(x,y)$ are mapped to different numbers $z$.

*(Reference: The Real Numbers: An Introduction to Set Theory and Analysis
by John Stillwell)*

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd like to see the sketch :)

Comment: I added a part.